# stick child to bottom when parent div touches the browser bottom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to stick child div to bottom when parent div touches the browser bottom.

***P.S : This should happen when the parent div is pushed down not when scrolled down.***

For example in my demo there is a content panel which is hidden. If you click on expand link you get to see the expanded content (which is pushing the `bottom_content` div to the bottom).

But accordion is just an example, there will be some other element which will be pushing the `bottom_content` div down. So I dont want to write stick function with reference to accordion.

It should stick down only when `bottom_content` div touches the bottom of the browser and when there is no much content in the page then the child div should stay as it is like child of the `bottom_content`

Parent div: `bottom_content`
Child div: `footer`

Here is my code currently used, which is not proper

```
$('.expandble_conetnt a').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        $(this).next('span').slideToggle();     
    }); 

//this is for stick to the bottom
var stickyHeaderbottom = $('.footer').offset().top;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > stickyHeaderbottom) {
            $('.footer').css({ position: 'fixed', bottom: '0px', width: '95%', left: '2.5%' });
        } else {
            $('.footer').css({ position: 'static', bottom: '0px', width: '100%' });

        }
    });
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/bonekowizuja/2)

Comment: Does [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5u7j14L/) have desired behaviour?

Comment: No. it is freezing the div on scroll. BUt i dont need this on scroll.

Comment: And [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5u7j14L/1/) to handle window resizing.

Comment: In fiddle position of `footer` changes not only on scrolling, but also after list opening.

Comment: @Regent Your answer worked perfectly. :) Thank you!! you can add the same in answer section.

Comment: You're welcome. Well, as it is correct one - I posted it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole idea is to handle `.footer` position on `window` scrolling, on `window` resizing and after `.slideToggle()` for the list is completed:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5u7j14L/1/).

```
var stickyHeaderbottom = $('.footer').offset().top;

$('.expandble_conetnt a').click(function()
{
    $(this).next('span').slideToggle(function()
    {
        handleBottom();
    });
    return false;
}); 

$(window).scroll(function()
{
    handleBottom();
});

$(window).resize(function()
{
    handleBottom();
});

function handleBottom()
{
    if ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() < $(document).height())
    {
        $('.footer').css({ position: 'fixed', bottom: '0', width: '95%', left: '2.5%' });
    }
    else
    {
        $('.footer').css({ position: 'absolute', bottom: '0', width: '100%', left: 0 });
    }
}
```

**Edit**. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5u7j14L/2/) without weird footer jumping after list opening.

```
var stickyHeaderbottom = $('.footer').offset().top;

$('.expandble_conetnt a').click(function()
{
    var toggledElement = $(this).next('span');
    handleBottom(toggledElement.height());
    toggledElement.slideToggle(function()
    {
        handleBottom();
    });
    return false;
}); 

$(window).scroll(function()
{
    handleBottom();
});

$(window).resize(function()
{
    handleBottom();
});

function handleBottom(additionalHeight)
{
    var pageHeight = $(document).height();
    if (additionalHeight)
    {
        pageHeight += additionalHeight;
    }
    if ($(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop() < pageHeight)
    {
        $('.footer').css({ position: 'fixed', bottom: '0', width: '95%', left: '2.5%' });
    }
    else
    {
        $('.footer').css({ position: 'absolute', bottom: '0', width: '100%', left: 0 });
    }
}
```

Comment: +1, Can this be changed to fix the footer when it gets to the viewport edge (preventing it from going past it). At the moment there is a delay as the footer is fixed when the content finishes expanding.

Comment: @misterManSam, yes, it looks quite weird. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e5u7j14L/2/) looks better, doesn't it?

Comment: Good stuff. Put it in a runnable stack snippet! :D

Answer (score 0):

you can make js on.change to change that div position to absolute and bottom:0 left:0