# Fixed div until footer is visible in viewport

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I was attempting to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2805404/preventing-element-from-displaying-on-top-of-footer-when-using-positionfixed).

However, it's not working. It's always firing the `else` removing the `sticky` class from the `div` regardless if the footer is in view or not.

Here's the code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var windowTop = $(this).scrollTop();        

    if (windowTop >= $("#site-footer").offset().top) {
        console.log('sticky!')
        $("div#desktop-cta").addClass("sticky-footer");
    } else {
        console.log('not sticky');
        $("div#desktop-cta").removeClass("sticky-footer");
    }
});
```

`site-footer` is the ID of the footer element of the page. `desktop-cta` is the element that requires the `sticky-footer` class to be added or removed. When looking at the console it only logs "not sticky".

How can it be fixed?

Comment: Your if condition is giving error. $("#site-footer").offset().top This is not working

Comment: If you do not have your own code (only one from mentioned answer), then you can also try [my code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25867126/stick-child-to-bottom-when-parent-div-touches-the-browser-bottom/25912519#25912519) from one of my previous answers. Maybe  it is what you want.

Comment: Yes, I know the if condition is what's giving me grief, but I don't know why.

Regent, I tried your code and it somewhat works, but it doesn't remove the sticky-footer class when #site-footer comes into view. It has to be all the way to the bottom of #site-footer then some weird flashing occurs...